# How To Add IP to htaccess allow list?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I got a problem with the following code in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(tv\.)?my-domain\.com:16500 [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(tv\.)?my-domain\.com:16500.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|js|txt|mp4|mp3)$ /redirect/error.mp4 [L]
```

So what this code does, is, it allows that **ONLY** tv.my-domain.com:16500 can stream the content that is in the folder where the `.htaccess` is located.

This all works fine BUT, what do I have to do if I want to add an IP address (together with the already existing rule for the domain) to the list of HTTP referees that are ALLOWED to access the files?

This code does NOT work:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(tv\.)?my-domain\.com:16500 [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(tv\.)?my-domain\.com:16500.*$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://?10.0.0.2:16500 [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://?10.0.0.2:16500.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|js|txt|mp4|mp3)$ /redirect/error.mp4 [L]
```

So, can someone please tell me what the correct way of doing this would be?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you need to use `%{REMOTE_ADDR}` and not `%{HTTP_REFERER}`for IP addresses.

So the syntax would be like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127\.0\.0\.1$
```

Make sure you clear your cache **before** testing this of course.